# How to wrap node with certain attribute?

Tags: xslt

I have in-document with XML code:

```
<root>
 <a id="att_1">
  <a id="att_2"/>
  <a id="att_3">
   <a id="att_4"> 
    <a id="att_5"/>
   </a>
   <a id="att_6"/>
  </a>
 </a>
</root>
```

I need out-document, where node with `id="att_6"` is wraped in `b` node:

```
<root>
 <a id="att_1">
  <a id="att_2"/>
  <a id="att_3">
   <a id="att_4"> 
    <a id="att_5"/>
   </a>
   <b>
    <a id="att_6"/>
   </b>
  </a>
 </a>
</root>
```

I try copy all nodes from in-document into out-doc firstly. Secondly I need to wrap one node with certain id. This is my stylesheet:

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <b>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".[@id = 'att_6']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a[@id='att_6']">
    <b>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </b>
</xsl:template>
```

You just need to match the node(s) you want to wrap and handle them as shown above.  `xsl:copy-of` does a deep copy of the context node and all its contained nodes.

Everything else is handled by the identity transform.

Comment: Ok, but what if I'll want to compute id in variable or pass it to template as param?

Comment: Remember "variables" in XSLT are not mutable after they've been created.  You need to edit your original post and explain more clearly what you are trying to do and how you intend to use a "variable" to select nodes. How will the value be determined? At what point?  This completely changes your question.